# Replace hyphen in front of scores/reputation by minus

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, vote-count

> (Actually a [dupe of another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71269/1968) but that was incorrectly closed so I’m posting here until the other question gets reopened, and this one merged.)

This has bugged me for ages. **The website uses hyphens in negative numbers throughout.** It should use the minus sign instead.

Of course it’s not *important*. It just looks really ugly.

The new reputation reporting tracker (thumbs up!) makes this particularly obvious:

[image: wrong]
[image: right]

Jin and waffles say on the other thread that for the SO font, the dash actually looks better than the minus sign but I think they made a mistake: They might have used the en-dash accidentally, which does indeed look even worse than the hyphen here.

Comment: Obligatory XKCD reference for this kind of discussions: http://xkcd.com/1015/

Comment: @sbi Has a point, this only bugs people who actually notice it. But those, it bugs hard. I can’t mentally “switch off” noticing bad typography.

Comment: Actually, my immediate thought was "What happens if I copy & paste those numbers into a spreadsheet program?" I suppose Excel will not be able to tell that a "—" (em-dash) is supposed to be a "-" (minus). Therefore I upvoted this question.

Comment: @sbi Wow, Excel sucks. :D I’ve tried it, it recognises neither dashes nor the Unicode minus sign U+2212

Comment: "I _suppose_ Excel will not be able to..." I haven't tried. Maybe it does. From a programmer's POV, it's still the wrong char, though. And I'm a programmer on a programmers' website. `:)`

Comment: Facetious comment first: since a hyphen is *not* part of the numerical representation of a number, all the supposed negative numbers on this site **are actually positive**!  This means that we need a *massive* rep recalc whereby all down-votes are actually counted positively.

Comment: Serious comment second: Forget Excel, I wonder how screen readers deal with this.  Do they read "hyphen ten"?  How is one supposed to know that that means *minus* ten?

Comment: Is it actually 'wrong', given that the character is named  `HYPHEN-MINUS` and ["used for either hyphen or minus sign"](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) ? (this is a serious question)

Comment: @AakashM Typographically, yes, it’s wrong. There can be no question – it’s simply rendered as a hyphen and those two characters are rendered completely different. The important point is that it doesn’t match the plus sign. The Unicode standard simply takes a realistic stance: since the hyphen has been in existence on typewriters much longer and the minus sign isn’t on any keyboard, it is entirely acceptable not to require a convoluted action to type the “correct” character. But this argument doesn’t apply here since the number display is generated by a software, not a person typing them.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what's the difference between a hyphen and a minus sign?  I thought they were the same character.  I know what an em-dash and an en-dash are, but I thought the `-` next to my equals sign was the same as the `-` in my number pad

Comment: @Jon - `However, in environments that are restricted to ISO 646, and often in computing generally, the hyphen is represented by a hyphen-minus ( - ), which is well known and easy to enter on keyboards.` so under what circumstances will there actually be a difference between a hyphen and a minus sign

Comment: @Adam:  Oops.  Misread the comment.  That I don't know.  Nothing?

Comment: @Adam The “minus” on your numblock isn’t a minus, it’s also the hyphen. However, there is a separate character (which is not available on common keyboard layouts) for a minus sign which renders subtly but fundamentally different: it is on the same height, and has the same width, as the “+” sign of the same font. Contrast this with the hyphen (just look at my screenshots). Once you know what the difference is, the wrong character becomes a jarring annoyance.

Comment: +1 Full ack. Just because lots of people don't care or can't tell doesn't mean we shouldn't be doing it right, especially if it's such a simple thing to get right.

Comment: Related question (TeX Meta): [Use dashes in page titles instead of hyphens](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/use-dashes-in-page-titles-instead-of-hyphens/4012), and still somewhat related (MSE): [Strange punctuation in "Congrats, you've gained the privilege" message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117979/strange-punctuation-in-congrats-youve-gained-the-privilege-banner/162565)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We won't be changing this, it adds way too much complexity to code that does something very, ***very*** simple...for very little benefit.

Comment: Not that I can see your code or anything, but... what does this have to do with code complexity?  Could you be, perhaps, misunderstanding the question?  From what I read, it's just using one character in place of another.

Comment: @Jon = `thisIsANegativeIntergerVariable.ToString()` is *effectively* what happens, the literal code is `@re.RepChange`, that's *it*.

Comment: Now I'm really confused.  Are you saying that some library's `ToString()` function outputs a [dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) as opposed to a [minus sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minus_sign#Minus_sign) for negative numbers?  If so, that's a bug in the library, I'd say.

Comment: @JonEricson - this is default razor view behavior, feel free to file a bug with Microsoft :)

Comment: Stepping off my high horse now... Ugh.  That's truly annoying and I feel your pain.  (Thanks for indulging my curiosity.)

Comment: GAHH!!! Is this a dash, or a hyphen?  Is Razor spitting out negative numbers with an em-dash, an en-dash, or a hyphen?  The question, and coments all seem to use them interchangeably.

Comment: So what you’re saying is effectively that you only have to replace `x.ToString()` with `x.TypographicallyCorrectToString()`, given an extension method which performs `return x < 0 ? '\u2212' + Math.Abs(x).ToString() : x.ToString()`? – **EDIT** I just see that, no, it’s not. It would at least necessitate patching the library. Well, I’m off to file a bug report then. It’s what I do today.

Comment: Did anything happen in the meantime?

Comment: Well [this has 254 votes on MSO as of this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317907/negative-question-scores-should-be-prefixed-with-a-%E2%88%92-minus-sign-instead-of-a)

Comment: @MartinUeding yes, 10 years passed.

Answer (score 11):

I’ll note that the recent achievements pop-up already uses true minus signs for reputation changes instead of hyphens.

Though this alone may not be enough to compel you to switch, [Codidact](https://codidact.com/) doesn’t have this problem.

Here’s a userscript.  The initial version took me about half an hour to write, so it did not require very much effort at all (and I am at a disadvantage in that I cannot easily identify every place where a negative value can appear, and fixing it up after-the-fact in the DOM adds considerable overhead; doing this server-side would be simpler and cleaner).  All it takes is some political will.

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Stack Exchange: minus signs
// @grant    none
// @run-at   document-start
// @match    https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match    https://*.superuser.com/*
// @match    https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match    https://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match    https://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match    https://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match    https://stackapps.com/*
// @exclude  https://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://openid.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude  https://contests.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude  /^https?:\/\/winterbash\d{4,}\.stackexchange\.com\//
// ==/UserScript==

const SELECTOR = `
  .rep-down,
  .ob-post-votes,
  .js-vote-count,
  .js-vote-count > .fc-red-600,
  .mini-counts,
  .mini-counts > :only-child,
  .answer-votes,
  .js-metadata-vote-count,
  .s-activity-indicator,
  .s-post-summary--stats-item,
  .s-post-summary--stats-item-number,
  .s-badge,
  .s-badge > span:only-child,
  .js-followed-post .fs-body3,
  .vote-count-post,
  .vote-count-post > :only-child,
  .flex--item > div,
  .vote,
  .-stats,
  .movedDown,
  .bounty-indicator-tab,
  td.event-comment > span > span
`;

const replaceHyphen = (obj, prop) => {
  const oldValue = `${obj[prop]}`;
  const newValue = oldValue.replace(/(?<=^|\s)\u002d(?=\d)/gu, '\u2212');
  if (oldValue !== newValue)
    obj[prop] = newValue;
};

const fixupNode = node => {
  if (!node.matches(SELECTOR))
    return;
  if (node.title)
    replaceHyphen(node, 'title');
  if (node.firstChild?.nodeType === document.TEXT_NODE)
    replaceHyphen(node.firstChild, 'data');
};

const fixupUnder = node => {
  fixupNode(node);
  for (const subnode of node.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR))
    fixupNode(subnode);
}

if (document.body)
  fixupUnder(document.body);

new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  for (const mut of mutations) {
    switch (mut.type) {
      case 'characterData':
        fixupNode(mut.target.parentNode);
        break;
      case 'attributes':
        fixupNode(mut.target);
        break;
      case 'childList':
        fixupUnder(mut.target);
        break;
    }
  }
}).observe(document, {
  childList: true,
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['title'],
  characterData: true,
  subtree: true,
});
```