# Vote count minus signs not readable in Segoe UI

Tags: feature-request, accessibility, unicode, fonts, typography

The recent [UI update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/145942) which changed Stack Overflow's fonts to system defaults makes negative vote counts *very* hard to read on Microsoft Windows (in its Segoe UI font):

[image: Screenshot of current design]

How could Microsoft chose such a bad system font, you might ask. Well, it's not Microsoft's fault. It's Stack Overflow's fault. Because the character to the left of the number is - (U+002D: HYPHEN-MINUS), not the semantically and typographically correct minus sign − (U+2212: MINUS SIGN).

If we change the character to the true minus sign (U+2212), the indicator becomes much more readable:

[image: Screenshot of proposed design]

This feature request has been made [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124216/145942) and it was *declined*. However, back then it was mainly a matter of aesthetics: now (as of 10 May 2021, with Segoe UI) it's also about readability and accessibility.

When I first saw the question in the screenshot above, I thought to myself, "Why does this Q have three upvotes?".

Comment: A prior request to change to the minus sign was [declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124216/377214).

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: Well, but today with Segoe UI, it is no longer merely a matter of aesthetics: it's about readability and accessibility.

Comment: I'd edit this to link to the earlier declined request and explain why its rationale is wrong today.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: Done.

Comment: I guess you'll get better results if you configure ClearType properly. I'm not seeing anything wrong with Chrome, Edge or Firefox, I'm also on Windows 10 20H2.

Comment: @iBugsaysReinstateMonica: I'm on Windows 7, 64-bit, Firefox 88.0.1. But irrespective of platform and browser, the minus sign *is* different from the hyphen minus (much longer, different vertical position, possibly different thickness).