# Are fonts going to be fixed?

Tags: feature-request, bug, accessibility, fonts

There is some weird [silence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/364048/timeline) since the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364048/299295) of the font change.

There are 30% of *unhappy* users, who downvoted the announcement. Isn't it enough to act?

Will there be any kind of reaction to [my feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364546/299295)? What is going on?

Every day I am coming here in hope of change. But there are still those new ugly fonts everywhere. It hurts my eyes to read posts on Stack Overflow (other sites are better, can't say for all though) and no, it will not stop hurting my eyes if you just plan to wait 6 to 8 weeks.

I am specifically unhappy with code blocks and `this kind of highlighting`, the font is simply inappropriate, it's harder to read, there are some problems `with alignments`, it jumps up `and down`, up `and down`... At this point my eyes are hurt and I can't read my own post anymore.

Comment: "There are 30% of unhappy users, who dovnote the announce, isn't it enough to act?" - if, by inference, the other 70% *are* happy, then no. If it were a clear majority, I would agree with you.

Comment: Sadly, the answer is very likely no.  Small tweaks, little fixes, sure, but no total rollback.  The best thing you can do is hope for [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364279/add-the-font-changes-as-options-in-our-preferences) FR to be implemented, or/and install the [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/8932/custom-fonts-user-script-revert-or-improve-the-font-updates).  A note, though:  If the other 70% are happy users, then it's not really enough to act.

Comment: The numbers are misleading. The announcement got lots of upvotes *before* the change went live, presumably because people believed the hype and assumed the devs knew what they were doing. Since it went live, the votes are split about 50%–50%.

Comment: They will not be. they don't give a about those of us who still have issues with the change.

Comment: For Ubuntu the font change was reverted based on feedback from unhappy users. So SE does listen and does act on feedback - at least for this specific situation.

Comment: Yes, and the issues i have with it were dismissed as fake.

Comment: ratio of up/downvotes does not have any influence on the actions of the company https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps

Comment: Considering the recent history of not-so-well received design changes, that SE didn't revert ([here](/a/353529/401803) and [here](/q/344874/401803)), I'm afraid they won't revert this as well (not even put this as an user preference, which was also [deferred](/q/364279/401803)). I guess we should give up on meta, as SE will simply do whatever they want, regardless of community feedback. They don't care about our opinion (sometimes they pretend they do, but that's all).